# Communication between a C console application and a Qt gui

Tags: c, qt, user-interface, console-application, communication

I have a console application written in C that simply takes an integer from user, and prints a text according to number given. I'd like to have a Qt based GUI that could send an integer to a C program, and read a string sent by that program. But I don't know how could I possibly make them communicate. Any ideas?

FYI: I don't want to merge my C program into Qt. They need to stay separate.

I'm using Qt 5.0.2 at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: What about storing in file and read at console application???

Comment: If they are running as seperate processes how about redirecting stdin and stdout using named pipes? Or you could use UNIX domain sockets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `QProcess` which will behave as an `IODevice` allowing to write (to stdin) or read (from stdout/stderr)

Check the example in the doc at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html for detailed example

- You Qt app would start your C program as a QProcess
- it will interact with it with write / readAllStandardOutput()
- wait for it to complete

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for QProcess (from the Qt-Doc):

```
 QObject *parent;
 ...
 QString program = "./path/to/Qt/examples/widgets/analogclock";
 QStringList arguments;
 arguments << "-style" << "motif";

 QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
 myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

You can `talk` with the process through channels.